# How to disable calling back from notification when iPhone is locked?

Tags: iphone, ios

When the phone is locked and I get a missed call I can just swipe it and it will call without requiring the passcode. How can I disable this function so that I need to enter the passcode?

Comment: Since the phone allows outgoing calls without the password and the missed call lists the phone number, this is inherently not possible.

Answer (score 2):

#### It is not possible, but will be soon.

As of right now, there is no toggle that can disable returning missed calls from the lockscreen, however, in iOS 11 (which will be publicly released in Fall 2017), you can disable this feature by toggling the switch in **Settings > TouchID & Passcode > Return missed calls**

[image: toggle pic]

Answer (score 1):

How to turn off Return Missed Calls on the Lock Screen

- Launch Settings from your Home screen.
- Tap Touch ID & Passcode.
- Enter your passcode.
- Tap the switch next to Return Missed Calls under Allow Access When Locked.